# Image sharing to face book is not working well

Tags: php, facebook, image, sharing

I am trying to share an image from my web site to facebook using php. But it shares only a thumbnail image and image link. I would like to get the full sized image instead of the image url.

This is my code

```
$attachment = array(

    'link' =>$_COOKIE['purl'],
    'picture' =>'http://cutefacebooktimelinecovers.com/'.$imgurl,
    'actions' => array(array(
            'name' => 'Cutefacebooktimelinecovers.com',
            'link' => 'http://cutefacebooktimelinecovers.com'
        ))
    );
    try {
        $result = $facebook->api(
        '/me/feed/',
        'post',
        $attachment
```

);

Comment: _“I would like to get the full sized image instead of the image url.”_ – then you don’t want to post a _link_ (what you are doing now), but post a photo to the user’s wall: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestion. I don't want to upload image to the users album . Just would like to post the image (not the url) to the users wall . Can I .?

Comment: $photo = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', 
    array(
     'source' => '@' .realpath($imgurl) ,
     'message' => ''
    )
   ); I s there any way to post to wall by using any thing instead of 'photos' in $facebook->api('/me/photos